# Sharing template struct among templates

Tags: c++, templates, struct, linked-list

In my everlasting effort to implement a link list I created a class-template representing the container (CursorList) and I have a seperate class-template that is supposed to be my iterator (CursorIterator).

In my CursorList I use a struct Node to represent elements of the list. I want to share this struct with my CursorIterator-Class (the iterator is pointing towards a Node). However this doesn't work as I want it to, I can't really get both classes to know the structures of Node.

CursorList.h

```
#ifndef CURSORLIST_H
#define CURSORLIST_H

#include "CursorIterator.h"

template <class T> class CursorList {
public:
    CursorList() {}

    typedef T value_type;
    typedef CursorIterator<T> iterator;

    bool empty() const;
    int size() const;
    T& front() const;
    void push_front(const T& item);
    void pop_front();

    iterator begin() const;
    iterator end() const;
    iterator insert(iterator itr, const T& value);
    iterator erase(iterator start, iterator stop);
    iterator erase(iterator itr);

    struct Node {
        Node(const T& n_data, Node* n_prev, Node* n_next): data(n_data), prev(n_prev), next(n_next) {}
        T data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
    };

private:
    Node* m_head;
};

#endif //CURSORLIST_H
```

CursorIterator.h

```
#ifndef CURSORITERATOR_H
#define CURSORITERATOR_H

template <class T> class CursorIterator {
private:
    typedef CursorIterator<T> iterator;
    Node* m_rep;

public:
    CursorIterator() {}
    CursorIterator(Node* n): m_rep(n) {}

    T& operator *();
    iterator& operator = (const iterator& rhs);
    bool operator != (const iterator& rhs) const;
    bool operator == (const iterator& rhs) const;
    iterator& operator ++();
    iterator operator ++(int);
};


#endif //CURSORITERATOR_H
```

Comment: `Node` should be `typename CursorList<T>::Node` in `CursorIterator`. But then you have dependency issues.

Comment: What about putting the Node class template in a separate file that both the list and the iterator include ?

Comment: `Node` is not necessarily nested inside `CursorList`, you can define `Node` first, then `CursorIterator` and `CursorList`; this will solve the dependency circling problem.